# Are there any scriptures which prescribe any remedy against fear of suffering?

Tags: scripture, vedas, karma, adi-shankaracharya, manuscripts

I'm talking about the fear of suffering. Not particularly death. Personally, I had been through many sufferings in life and I'm still going through mental and physical sufferings. I really want to achieve something with my life. But I really couldn't achieve anything. I'm kinda living in a constant fear of future hurdles and sufferings. I just want to feel assured that future is going to be ok. But I know that it's impossible.
I know that everything is my prarabdha karma. And I have to live with it. What I truly want is atleast a bit of courage and work out something with my life.I just hope that I find some solace, peace and courage for overcoming my fear of hurdles.

Answer (score 1):

Nārāyaṇa-kavaca is prescribed for fear. It is found in [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 6.8](https://archive.org/details/kvrE_shrimad-bhagavata-mahapurana-english-of-c.-l.-goswami-m.-a-shastri-part-1-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/586/mode/2up)
, where instructions are given. Verse 5 says it is to be used "bhaya āgate", "in face of danger". It has the effect of "sādhvasāt sa vimucyate", "rid of fear" (verse 36) to those who meet its user. It frees the user from dangers (37), and the user is "mucyate sarvato bhayāt", "rid of all fear" (41).

Most importantly, [Gita 2.40](https://archive.org/details/bhagavadgita_bhashya_and_tatparya_nirnaya_of_madhvacharya_-_nagesh_d_sonde/page/n45/mode/2up), tells us that "sv-alpam apy asya dharmasya
trāyate mahato bhayāt", "Even a little effort in the righteous path [of yoga] will deliver you from great fear."